# listFiles() returns null when it shouldn't. It used to work properly until recently and hasn't been modified

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, nullpointerexception, access-rights

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(true)
    {
        ArrayList<File> wallpapers = new ArrayList<File>();
        File dir = new File("C:/Windows/System32/oobe/info/backgrounds/");
        if(dir.listFiles() == null)
            System.out.println("Empty");
        for(File img : dir.listFiles())
        {
            if(img.getName().endsWith(".jpg") && img.getName() != "backgroundDefault.jpg")
                wallpapers.add(img);
        }
        File current = new File("C:/Windows/System32/oobe/info/backgrounds/backgroundDefault.jpg");
        int i = 1;
        for(File img : wallpapers)
        {
            File f = new File("C:/Windows/System32/oobe/info/backgrounds/"+ i++ +".jpg");
            current.renameTo(f);
            File file = new File("C:/Windows/System32/oobe/info/backgrounds/backgroundDefault.jpg");
            img.renameTo(file);
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        }

    }
}   }
}
```

This code changes the background image of the Windows Log In screen every minute.
listFiles() returns null for dir and I get a NullPointerException on for(File img : dir.listFiles()). I thought there may be a problem with file rights so I tried to change the file path to a directory I have on my Desktop and it works fine. So I'm assuming I can't access system files because my program doesn't have enough rights. Let me also precise that this code used to work fine until recently. It hasn't been modified. I just found out that my Log In Wallpaper doesn't change anymore.
Even when the program did work I couldn't modify the file name when I launched the program through Eclipse but I would export it as .jar and schedule it with Task Scheduler with highest privileges to give it admin rights and it worked without any problems until recently. I also tried ignoring the errors thinking they were related to access rights and tried to launch my executable jar with highest privileges through Task Scheduler and also using a batch file. I even tried launching the jar through a cmd I opened with Administrator Rights to no avail it still says NullPointerException in the cmd. I'm kind of lost and would appreciate any help.

Comment: I have this problem on JDK 11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Windows 7 (and later) the process will have to run with elevated privileges to **write** to `C:/Windows` and similar directories. But if that was the problem it would result in a different error message.

What I suspect:
When running a 32-bit JVM under 64-bit Windows `new File("C:/Windows/System32")` will point to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` and there is no `info`-Folder under `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oobe`

As a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File sysdir = new File("C:/Windows/System32/oobe/info");
    for(File file:sysdir.listFiles()) {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
}
```

runs fine with 64-bit-JRE and throws `NullPointerException` under 32-bit-JRE on Windows 7 64-bit.

So perhaps you or another application recently installed a 32-bit-jre or changed your path to point to a 32-bit-jre and thus broke your application.

Comment: That was it. I'm running a 64bit Windows 7 and I recently changed my jre from 64bit to 32bit. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just came across the same problem, but with a 64-bit JDK on 64-bit Win 7, where `C:\Documents and Settings` returns `true` to `isDirectory()`, but returns `null` (not even an empty `File` array!) to a `listFiles()` call in an RCP desktop app. All you can do is add a check, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

> listFiles() returns null for dir and I get a NullPointerException on for(File img : dir.listFiles()).

It "returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs". So either it isn't a directory, or an I/O error occurred.

You need to code defensively against this possibility rather than just contra-factually assert that "it shouldn't". It did, and it can.

Maybe you should remove the trailing `/.`

Comment: I tried dir.isDirectory() and it returns false. Appearently my directory isn't a directory. Which doesn't make sense to me. I tried both with / and without. And it's a legitimate directory and there shouldn't be errors in the path name since I copy pasted it and replaced \ with /. And what I don't understand it used to work perfectly until recently.

Comment: So it isn't a directory, at least to you. Maybe it's a permission problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare strings with `==`

```
if(img.getName().endsWith(".jpg") && img.getName() != "backgroundDefault.jpg")
```

Use equals

```
if(img.getName().endsWith(".jpg") && !(img.getName()).equals("backgroundDefault.jpg"))
```

Answer (score -5):

If you get a `NullPointerException` on the line `for(File img : dir.listFiles())` that means that the variable `dir` is `null` and you can't call `listFiles()` on it. Have you tried debugging it and see if maybe the directory path has changed or that `dir` is in fact set properly?

Comment: 'Most likely?' It can't mean anything else.

Comment: dir is indeed null. I tried checking if it was a directory with dir.isDirectory() which returns false. Which I can't explain because it  is a directory and the path name is correct. And besides it used to work the way it is until recently. Neither the directory nor the code were modified.

Comment: I'll edit the very unfortunate term 'most likely' out then, excuse my inexpertise in the English language.

Comment: @Octoshape Do you have some *evidence* about who downvoted this question? Or are you just speculating pointlessly?

Comment: @EJP It *was* speculation. Since you were the only one commenting negatively on my answer that was my deduction but apparently not pointless since it got me where/what I wanted :) but please excuse me if I came across aggressive.